# Find the nearest 2^i value to integer n

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to find and compare the nearest 2^i value to  the input 'n ' (refer to the snippet below), as for now it just gets struck at i=i, whereas i want it to output that 'i' which would give me the nearest 2^i w.r.t n...

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<math.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {long n;
        int i,t;
        cin>>t;
        while(t--)
        {cin>>n;
        for(i=1;i<30;i++)
        {
        if(pow(2,i)<=n<=pow(2,i+1))
        break;

        }cout<<pow(2,i);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem. For some specified input, what is your expected and actual output? Please edit your question to include that information (also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: But a good candidate for your problem is the expression `pow(2,i)<=n<=pow(2,i+1)`. C++ is not math, you can't use conditions the same way as you do in math. The expression `pow(2,i)<=n<=pow(2,i+1)` doesn't really do what you expect it to do.

Comment: just few hints you do not need pow or even log2 ... why not use bit-shift of 1 until it hits flips the `n` comparison?

Comment: Your code doesn't return the nearest power, but the largest power that does no exceed n.

Comment: Assuming (p=1<<i) < n && n < (P=2<<i), is _nearest_ supposed to mean `n - p < P - n ? p : P` or `(long)n*n < (long)P*p ? p : P` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By linear search**:

You update the index `i` in such a way that `2^i <= n` is always true, and make `i` as large as possible, i.e. until `n < 2^(i+1)`:

```
i= 0 # 2^0 <= n, provided 1 <= n
while (2 << i) <= n: # 2^(i+1) <= n
    i= i+1 # 2^i <= n
# 2^i <= n < 2^(i+1)
```

CAUTION: this code fails for `n >= 2^31`, as the shift `2 << i` overflows.

The while loop will be executed between 0 and 31 times.

**By dichotomic search**:

You keep two indexes, in such a way that `2^i<=n<2^j`. Then you consider a third index halfway of `i` and `j` and find the subinterval that contains `n`.

```
i= 0 # 2^i <= 1, provided 1 <= n
j= 32 # n < 2^32, assuming 32 bits unsigned; then 2^i <= n < 2^j
while j - i > 1:
    k= (i + j) >> 1
    if (1 << k) <= n: # 2^k <= n
        i= k # 2^i <= n < 2^j
    else: # n < 2^j 
        j= k # 2^i <= n < 2^j
# 2^i <= n < 2^(i+1), as j == i+1
```

The while loop will be executed exactly 5 times only !

**By exponential/dichotomic search**:

You can use a variant if you expect that the values of `n` are more frequently small than large.

Perform `<=` comparisons with `2^1`, `2^2`, `2^4`, `2^8` and `2^16`, in that order. This takes between 1 and 5 comparisons. Then you will have a bracketing of `n` that encompasses `2^1`, `2^2`, `2^4`, `2^8` or `2^16` elements, which you will nail down by dichotomy, requiring 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 additional comparisons.

Comment: Caution, I didn't check thoroughly.

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer !!, all we need to do is, put the && operator...as given below...

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<math.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {long n;
    int i,t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<30;i++)
    {
    if((pow(2,i)<=n)&&(pow(2,i+1)>n))
    break;

    }cout<<pow(2,i);
    }
    }
```

Comment: It is useless to test `pow(2,i) <= n`.